# Ignore part of statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I've got a number of SQL statements executing in my application like so:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(statement, connection))
   {
      adapter.Fill(dtResults);
   }
}
```

Each statement can have an `AS` clause, for example: `SELECT id AS 'Customer ID' FROM table`. Is it possible to ignore the `AS` part of the statement, essentially sending the real column name to the DataTable?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the input?

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I've got hundreds of SQL statements in the system, which would result in manually changing them all :/

Comment: Do it then. Fix the problem instead of putting a sticking plaster on it.

Comment: @JonSkeet The thing is that it's hundreds of queries "in theory". What I'm working on is a query generator, and basically builds SQL code based on user input. By default the SQL statements employ an `AS` clause so as to display the respective column's metadata. However, when exporting results to Excel, I would not like to display columns based on metadata. Thus, my options are to generate another SQL statement without `AS` clauses (basically going over all my SQL generation code classes), or find some other way.

Comment: It sounds like fixing your SQL generation classes to have "with aliases" and "without aliases" it the way to go then.

Comment: You could write a string parser to remove the as xxxx text from the SQL statement itself and wrap your statements with the function that does the parsing (including a bool option to remove/not remove the AS text)

Comment: @DotNET; you already have the data in the grid, and you already have both the original column name AND the alias column name in your metadata (how else did you generate the query). So just write your export routine to translate alias to original.

Comment: @StephenByrne - Actually the DataTable essentially displays the metadata. SQL expressions like this are being formed into the DataTable: `SELECT id AS 'Customer ID' FROM table`. So the DataTable's columns would only be the metadata.

Comment: @DotNET, I understand that, what I am trying to say is that at the point where you display the DataGrid, you have access to all of the information you need to export it with the original column names.
Either you have kept a reference to your SQL Generation object by the time you get to the data table display, which itself must have some kind of mapping between original->display columns, OR you can just use the display column names in the data table to lookup the meta-data you previously used from the database, in order to get the original column names, when the user clicks "Export" or whatever

Comment: @StephenByrne - Yes, it's no problem at all to access the original columns. The only thing is that the solution I came up with basically involves generating 2 SQL statements - one for meta data (including the `AS` clause) and another for the real data (without the `AS` clause). I apologise if i'm not understanding your point, but I'll try reading again tomorrow - too tired now. But at this stage I think my best bet would be to just generate 2 SQL statements - one for each case

Comment: @JonSkeet - Could you post your suggestion of fixing the input as an answer please, so that I could accept it? As that's the approach I've decided to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always keen on fixing a problem as close to the source as I can, rather than fixing it "downstream" so to speak.

In this case, it sounds like the problem is that your SQL generators aren't as flexible as they need to be. You need to change them so that you can control whether or not they emit the `AS` aliasing within the query. That's likely to be more reliable than post-processing the "incorrect" query - and means that your code can clearly express what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is what I've done, and I have to agree - it was the better choice :) Thanks for the suggestion and +1 !

Comment: @DotNET: Sometimes it just takes another person reassuring you that the "slower but better" long term fix is worthwhile compared with the quick and dirty hack that would hurt eventually ;)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.  What about changing the column names in dtResults after it's filled, though?

Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve more specifically?

Comment: Basically I'm building an SQL generator, which can generate SQL statements with column names based on meta-data within the database, when being displayed in a Datagrid. However, users can export the data, and on doing so it would have to use the real values.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you were able to SET SHOWPLAN_XML on, run the statement and get the column mappings, then run it again with showplan_xml off. I don't know if this would work in your particular case as obviously in general it wouldn't help (select price * quantity as total) but for your purposes it might.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have a table of tables with column names and display names and then in the DataTable I use the display name as the ColumnName.